# Value error problem I encountered with tensorflow optimizer parameter

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Value error problem using tensorflow
I have an issue from part of my tensor flow code when building a neural network: The error is a

```
ValueError: Argument(s) not recognized : {'lr' : 0.001}
```

The section of my code referred to is:

```
model.compile( loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer=keras.optimizer.Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=["accuracy"],)
```

Any ideas?

After importing the required models (following tensorflow tutorial)
such as keras; likewise layers and models from tensorflow.keras, and mnist from tensorflow.keras.darasets

I set model equals

```
keras.sequential....
model.compile...
model.fit...
model.evaluate.
```

After all this, instead of getting the accuracy of my training and testing datasets I defined in my code, I get the value error

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
              metrics=['mae']
)
```

It's no longer "lr". You want to use "learning_rate".

Comment: Thank you so much, a question I've had for days, was answered in minutes by the you, through a good channel (stackoverflow).

Comment: Now I can move on with my coding...God bless you.

Comment: A short look into the docs of TF Adam would also answer the question. In the beginning, docs can seem cryptic, but they are very useful to look things up fast.

Comment: The issue is many videos teach using lr= & I came across this exact problem. So I'm glad I could help out.

Comment: Alright. So where can I find the docs of TF Adam?

Comment: @IseseleVictor https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam